# How to write unit test when expect very long

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing

I think the expected results are been a hard code but my expected results in my test are very long and duplicated pattern. and I have same case about 3 case.

I should write this expected results following this:

```
public function testConvertTargetByWeek()
{
   $revenue = 100;
   $week = 50;

   $revenueByWeeks = convertRevenueByWeek($revenue, $week);

   $expects = array(
     1 => 2,
     2 => 4,
     ...
     50 => 100,
   );

   $this->assertEquals($expects, $revenueByWeeks);
}
```

or

```
public function testConvertTargetByWeek()
{
   $revenue = 100;
   $week = 50;

   $revenueByWeeks = convertRevenueByWeek($revenue, $week);

   for(range(1, 50) as $_week)
   {
      $expect[$week] = $revenue * ($_week / $week);
   }

   $this->assertEquals($expects, $revenueByWeeks);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are the same then you could pull them out as a property of the test class. I don't necessarily see anything wrong with having large values as your expected value as in some cases it can be necessary (testing the response of a controller etc), but you could also break your tests down further and have individual tests which test whether certain subsections of the large response match a pattern.